# pytest monkeypatch a function that returns two values

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a function as the following and I want to mock using monkeypatch

```py
cmd_a, cmd_b = get_cmds()
```

so I use the following

```py
monkeypatch.setattr('get_cmds', MagicMock())
```

and it throws

```
 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Any suggestion to mock this function?

Answer (score 0):

So this works.

```py
 mock_get_cmds = MagicMock()
 mock_get_cmds.return_value = "test", "test"
 monkeypatch.setattr('get_cmds', mock_get_cmds)
```